# DC-DC buck converter inrush start on voltage

Tags: buck, voltage-measurement, debugging, ripple

I started to examine the behavior of the converters on my custom board. The input to the converter comes from an external supply with a voltage of 20 V, the required output voltage is ~12 V.

When I turn it on I put a trigger on the output voltage of the converter and I observe the following phenomenon:

[image]

It's strange to me because I didn't see the same phenomenon in the simulation of LTSpice.

This is the schematic design of the DC/DC buck converter (N.A = not fitted):

[image]

I'm afraid it's related to the cable at the SS input, but on the other hand, if I add it as soon as someone externally turns off the 24 V voltage, the voltage on the capacitor will remain for some time and won't turn off immediately.

Should I do something else?

This is the simulation result:

[image]

Comment: The output can't reach 12V instantly. It has to rapidly ramp up inductor current each switching cycle until the output voltage reaches the target, which could look like the waveform shown. What does your simulation show?

Comment: @Unimportant See the pic right now attached

Comment: The datasheet mentions switching freq. foldback during overload conditions and startup (charging the output caps). It might be this slow switching you see in your waveform. The simulation might not account for this. The datasheet does not say the actual foldback frequency so can't say for sure.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the soft-start pin, they are your friends. In this case, it might prevent some needy output capacitors stealing the show.

Comment: The ESR and ESL of the input and output caps matters (including parasitics from layout).  What does your pcb layout look like?

Comment: Both comments are good.  If you do not use the soft start, the current limit will cause the frequency foldback and the sawtooth is the result.  To get optimum turn-on time, you must choose the correct soft start components to keep you out of current limit.  You can pull the SS capacitor down at power-down with a diode to Vin.